# CakePHP3 custom finder method using contain and does not work when attempt to display the associated model field

Tags: php, orm, cakephp-3.0

This is my custom finder method inside DynamicViewsTable.php

```
public function findAccessibleByUser(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        if (empty($options['User']['id'])) {
            throw new Exception("Current User not set", 1);    
        }

        $query->select(['DynamicViews.id', 'DynamicViews.title', 'UsersAccessDynamicViews.ordinal_ranking'])
              ->contain(['UsersAccessDynamicViews'])
              ->where([
                    'UsersAccessDynamicViews.user_id' => $options['User']['id'],
                ])
              ->order(['UsersAccessDynamicViews.ordinal_ranking' => 'ASC']);
        return $query;
    }
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'UsersAccessDynamicViews.ordinal_ranking' in 'field list'
```

and the query shown in the error page is:

```
SELECT DynamicViews.id AS `DynamicViews__id`, DynamicViews.title AS `DynamicViews__title`, UsersAccessDynamicViews.ordinal_ranking AS `UsersAccessDynamicViews__ordinal_ranking` FROM dynamic_views DynamicViews WHERE UsersAccessDynamicViews.user_id = :c0 ORDER BY UsersAccessDynamicViews.ordinal_ranking ASC
```

DynamicViews hasMany UsersAccessDynamicViews

Comment: How are the two tables related?

Comment: Updated question.  Essentially DynamicViews hasMany UsersAccessDynamicViews

Comment: That is your mistake, you cannot query in the hasMany direction. Go the other way, querying the UsersAccessDynamicViews which can directly left join the DynamicViews.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can include any type of associaition using `contain()`, matching something does only work for `1:1` and `n:1` associations, that is `hasOne` and `belongsTo`, as these are the only associations where `contain()` will join in the related tables.

For all other purposes you will have to use either **[`matching()`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data)** (requires a recent dev snapshot in order to work when combined with `contain()`, escpecially [**for more complex combinations**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5584))

```
$query
    ->select(['DynamicViews.id', 'DynamicViews.title', 'UsersAccessDynamicViews.ordinal_ranking'])
    ->contain(['UsersAccessDynamicViews'])
    ->matching('UsersAccessDynamicViews', function ($q) use ($options) {
        return $q->where([
            'UsersAccessDynamicViews.user_id' => $options['User']['id']
        ]);
    })
    ->order(['UsersAccessDynamicViews.ordinal_ranking' => 'ASC']);
```

**[join in](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)** the related tables manually:

```
$query
    ->select(['DynamicViews.id', 'DynamicViews.title', 'UsersAccessDynamicViews.ordinal_ranking'])
    ->contain(['UsersAccessDynamicViews'])
    ->innerJoin('UsersAccessDynamicViews', [
        'UsersAccessDynamicViews.dynamic_view_id = DynamicViews.id',
        'UsersAccessDynamicViews.user_id' => $options['User']['id']
    ])
    ->order(['UsersAccessDynamicViews.ordinal_ranking' => 'ASC']);
```

or query from the other table.

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins**

Comment: thank you for this most detailed answer. I am going to send a PR to improve the docs